# Zen Cart Echo Customers email address in my html form

Tags: php, html

I would like to have a html form added in the create_account_success page. Since zen cart has put the customers email address in the db, so I would like to echo the customers email address in this form, so customers no need to key in again. However I have tried several method still cannot echo the customers_email_address, by any chance any people can help?

```
<div class="centerColumn" id="createAcctSuccess">
<h1 id="createAcctSuccessHeading"><?php echo HEADING_TITLE; ?></h1>

<div id="createAcctSuccessMainContent" class="content"><?php echo TEXT_ACCOUNT_CREATED; ?></div>

<?php
if(REWARD_POINTS_NEW_ACCOUNT_REWARD!=0 && isset($RewardPoints))
 if(REWARD_POINTS_NEW_ACCOUNT_REWARD>0 && GetCustomersRewardPoints($_SESSION['customer_id'])==0)
  $RewardPoints->AddRewardPoints($_SESSION['customer_id'],REWARD_POINTS_NEW_ACCOUNT_REWARD);
 else
  if(REWARD_POINTS_NEW_ACCOUNT_REWARD<0 && GetCustomersPendingPoints($_SESSION['customer_id'])==0)
   $RewardPoints->AddPendingPoints($_SESSION['customer_id'],abs(REWARD_POINTS_NEW_ACCOUNT_REWARD));
?>







<fieldset>
<legend><?php echo PRIMARY_ADDRESS_TITLE; ?></legend>
<?php
/**
 * Used to loop thru and display address book entries
 */
  foreach ($addressArray as $addresses) {
?>
<h3 class="addressBookDefaultName"><?php echo zen_output_string_protected($addresses['firstname'] . ' ' . $addresses['lastname']); ?></h3>

<address><?php echo zen_address_format($addresses['format_id'], $addresses['address'], true, ' ', '<br />'); ?></address>

<div class="buttonRow forward"><?php echo '<a href="' . zen_href_link(FILENAME_ADDRESS_BOOK_PROCESS, 'edit=' . $addresses['address_book_id'], 'SSL') . '">' . zen_image_button(BUTTON_IMAGE_EDIT_SMALL, BUTTON_EDIT_SMALL_ALT) . '</a> <a href="' . zen_href_link(FILENAME_ADDRESS_BOOK_PROCESS, 'delete=' . $addresses['address_book_id'], 'SSL') . '">' . zen_image_button(BUTTON_IMAGE_DELETE, BUTTON_DELETE_ALT) . '</a>'; ?></div>
<br class="clearBoth">
<?php
  }
?>
</fieldset>


<div class="buttonRow forward"><?php echo '<a href="' . $origin_href . '">' . zen_image_button(BUTTON_IMAGE_CONTINUE, BUTTON_CONTINUE_ALT) . '</a>'; ?></div>
</div>
```

Form

```
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-081711.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
    #mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
    /* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
       We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
</style>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="http://c.us7.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=8e1a686f2e7899f845cd4208c&amp;id=79af0d8b9f" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <h2>Subscribe to our mailing list</h2>
<div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
</label>
    <input type="email" value="<?php echo $customers_email_address;?>" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-FNAME">First Name  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="required" id="mce-FNAME">
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-LNAME">Last Name  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="LNAME" class="required" id="mce-LNAME">
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-MMERGE4">Where did you hear about us?  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="MMERGE4" class="required" id="mce-MMERGE4">
</div>
    <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
        <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
    </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"><input type="text" name="b_8e1a686f2e7899f845cd4208c_79af0d8b9f" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
</form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var fnames = new Array();var ftypes = new Array();fnames[0]='EMAIL';ftypes[0]='email';fnames[1]='FNAME';ftypes[1]='text';fnames[2]='LNAME';ftypes[2]='text';fnames[4]='MMERGE4';ftypes[4]='text';
try {
    var jqueryLoaded=jQuery;
    jqueryLoaded=true;
} catch(err) {
    var jqueryLoaded=false;
}
var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
if (!jqueryLoaded) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js';
    head.appendChild(script);
    if (script.readyState && script.onload!==null){
        script.onreadystatechange= function () {
              if (this.readyState == 'complete') mce_preload_check();
        }    
    }
}

var err_style = '';
try{
    err_style = mc_custom_error_style;
} catch(e){
    err_style = '#mc_embed_signup input.mce_inline_error{border-color:#6B0505;} #mc_embed_signup div.mce_inline_error{margin: 0 0 1em 0; padding: 5px 10px; background-color:#6B0505; font-weight: bold; z-index: 1; color:#fff;}';
}
var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var style= document.createElement('style');
style.type= 'text/css';
if (style.styleSheet) {
  style.styleSheet.cssText = err_style;
} else {
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(err_style));
}
head.appendChild(style);
setTimeout('mce_preload_check();', 250);

var mce_preload_checks = 0;
function mce_preload_check(){
    if (mce_preload_checks>40) return;
    mce_preload_checks++;
    try {
        var jqueryLoaded=jQuery;
    } catch(err) {
        setTimeout('mce_preload_check();', 250);
        return;
    }
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'http://downloads.mailchimp.com/js/jquery.form-n-validate.js';
    head.appendChild(script);
    try {
        var validatorLoaded=jQuery("#fake-form").validate({});
    } catch(err) {
        setTimeout('mce_preload_check();', 250);
        return;
    }
    mce_init_form();
}
function mce_init_form(){
    jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
      var options = { errorClass: 'mce_inline_error', errorElement: 'div', onkeyup: function(){}, onfocusout:function(){}, onblur:function(){}  };
      var mce_validator = $("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").validate(options);
      $("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").unbind('submit');//remove the validator so we can get into beforeSubmit on the ajaxform, which then calls the validator
      options = { url: 'http://candles.us7.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=8e1a686f2e7899f845cd4208c&id=79af0d8b9f&c=?', type: 'GET', dataType: 'json', contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    beforeSubmit: function(){
                        $('#mce_tmp_error_msg').remove();
                        $('.datefield','#mc_embed_signup').each(
                            function(){
                                var txt = 'filled';
                                var fields = new Array();
                                var i = 0;
                                $(':text', this).each(
                                    function(){
                                        fields[i] = this;
                                        i++;
                                    });
                                $(':hidden', this).each(
                                    function(){
                                        var bday = false;
                                        if (fields.length == 2){
                                            bday = true;
                                            fields[2] = {'value':1970};//trick birthdays into having years
                                        }
                                        if ( fields[0].value=='MM' && fields[1].value=='DD' && (fields[2].value=='YYYY' || (bday && fields[2].value==1970) ) ){
                                            this.value = '';
                                        } else if ( fields[0].value=='' && fields[1].value=='' && (fields[2].value=='' || (bday && fields[2].value==1970) ) ){
                                            this.value = '';
                                        } else {
                                            if (/\[day\]/.test(fields[0].name)){
                                                this.value = fields[1].value+'/'+fields[0].value+'/'+fields[2].value;                                           
                                            } else {
                                                this.value = fields[0].value+'/'+fields[1].value+'/'+fields[2].value;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                            });
                        $('.phonefield-us','#mc_embed_signup').each(
                            function(){
                                var fields = new Array();
                                var i = 0;
                                $(':text', this).each(
                                    function(){
                                        fields[i] = this;
                                        i++;
                                    });
                                $(':hidden', this).each(
                                    function(){
                                        if ( fields[0].value.length != 3 || fields[1].value.length!=3 || fields[2].value.length!=4 ){
                                            this.value = '';
                                        } else {
                                            this.value = 'filled';
                                        }
                                    });
                            });
                        return mce_validator.form();
                    }, 
                    success: mce_success_cb
                };
      $('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').ajaxForm(options);


    });
}
function mce_success_cb(resp){
    $('#mce-success-response').hide();
    $('#mce-error-response').hide();
    if (resp.result=="success"){
        $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').show();
        $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').html(resp.msg);
        $('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').each(function(){
            this.reset();
        });
    } else {
        var index = -1;
        var msg;
        try {
            var parts = resp.msg.split(' - ',2);
            if (parts[1]==undefined){
                msg = resp.msg;
            } else {
                i = parseInt(parts[0]);
                if (i.toString() == parts[0]){
                    index = parts[0];
                    msg = parts[1];
                } else {
                    index = -1;
                    msg = resp.msg;
                }
            }
        } catch(e){
            index = -1;
            msg = resp.msg;
        }
        try{
            if (index== -1){
                $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').show();
                $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').html(msg);            
            } else {
                err_id = 'mce_tmp_error_msg';
                html = '<div id="'+err_id+'" style="'+err_style+'"> '+msg+'</div>';

                var input_id = '#mc_embed_signup';
                var f = $(input_id);
                if (ftypes[index]=='address'){
                    input_id = '#mce-'+fnames[index]+'-addr1';
                    f = $(input_id).parent().parent().get(0);
                } else if (ftypes[index]=='date'){
                    input_id = '#mce-'+fnames[index]+'-month';
                    f = $(input_id).parent().parent().get(0);
                } else {
                    input_id = '#mce-'+fnames[index];
                    f = $().parent(input_id).get(0);
                }
                if (f){
                    $(f).append(html);
                    $(input_id).focus();
                } else {
                    $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').show();
                    $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').html(msg);
                }
            }
        } catch(e){
            $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').show();
            $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').html(msg);
        }
    }
}

</script>
<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// Query the database for customers email address by (logged in) customer's ID
$email_results = $db->Execute('SELECT customers_email_address FROM customers WHERE customers_id = ' . $_SESSION['customer_id']);

// The customer's Email Address is now in the PHP variable $email_addr
$email_addr = $email_results->fields['customers_email_address'];
```